# Xcode 4 project: utility to clean up pbxproj file?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have an Xcode 4 project with 2 targets, one for iPhone and one for iPad. If I click on the iPad target and try to go to Build Settings Xcode 4 crashes:

> Encountered multiple assertions. First assertion was: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-269/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/FileTypes/../PBXFileType.m:594
>   Details:  filename should be a non-empty string, but it is nil

Obviously the pbxproj file has a bad reference in there somewhere -- likely caused by the many manual merges I've been forced to do by git. Is there some way to clean up the pbxproj file so it works correctly again or to tell which line is causing the problem?? I'd really *really* prefer not to have to recreate the project from scratch.

Comment: Glad you found a solution (and Knowledge is Power and all) but … if you're using Git, why not just revert to a good state? Worst case scenario: you have to clean up references to removed project members or add files back into the project.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried gorbster's method with no success (though it has solved similar problems for me in the past).

I went into my `project.pbxproj` file (inside the `.xcodeproj` package for the project) and found two lines that looked a little suspicious, both of the form:

```
53A45F8F138FE6F40077017F /* (null) in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; };
```

I deleted the lines, and voilà: I can access my build settings for this target again.

No idea how they got in there in the first place. I would guess something to do with a faulty merge under SVN.

Comment: This is a great find. Thank you. I didn't realize there would be an actual "(null)" text string in the `.xcodeproj` that I could search for and delete. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Did not find (null) values in the project.pbxproj. Even tried deleting  user-specific .xcuserdatad folder. But still xcode crashes on tapping the build settings. Any solution please ?

Answer (score 15):

Ran into the same issue this morning after pulling a colleague's merge.

I was able to fix this with the following:

1. Close Xcode
2. Open the **.xcodeproj** package in Finder
3. Delete the **project.xcworkspace** file/package
4. Open the **xcuserdata** folder and delete your **user-specific .xcuserdatad** folder.
5. Re-Open Xcode and project

I lost some minor user preferences (file and tab history, etc), but can now click all (9) of my targets without issue. Turns out my colleague was on an earlier version of Xcode, but I'm not sure if this contributed to the IDE crashing.

Comment: I followed these, can at least click on the target again without a crash, but if I click on "Build Settings", it crashes with this same error.

Comment: Although this didn't help my issue, I imagine it would be useful for a lot of people. +1.

Answer (score 10):

Ben Mosher found the solution.
And yes it is due to SVN merge problem.

As we working in team with SVN the error occur often so I wrote a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed "/(null) in/d" project.pbxproj > tmp_project.pbxproj
mv tmp_project.pbxproj project.pbxproj
```

Comment: Nice! I don't run into this super frequently (though this is likely due to the fact that we only have two committers on my team so far), but I'll be sure to borrow this if it becomes a less-than-occasional problem.

Comment: why not just `sed -i "/(null) in/d" project.pbxproj` ?

Answer (score 8):

Try the following steps while your Xcode is closed.

1. Go to your **{YOUR_PROJECT}.xcodeproj** file in finder.
2. Right click on the **{YOUR_PROJECT}.xcodeproj** file.
3. Choose **Show Package Contents** ...    this will open the contents in another Finder screen.
4. Open file **project.pbxproj** and search for all lines having string "**(null) in**"
5. Delete all lines having  **(null) in** ... no worries.... delete    confidently.
6. Save your file.

Now open your project using Xcode and try to open the Build Settings tab... hopefully your problem will be solved.

Thanks,
Mohamed.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your .xcodeproj file and "Show Package Contents".

Then open project.pbxproj file with TextEdit and duplicate.

Save duplicate file anywhere with same name and extension. (project.pbxproj)

And replace with the old file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you also tried the remove (null) reference lines and deleting the **user-specific .xcuserdatad** folder, and those did not work, here is a potential solution. FYI... This was experienced on Xcode 7.3.1 .

Here is the scenario I faced:

I experienced this issue that was triggered by having "twin" branches in a git repo... (i.e. one branch BRANCH_A is a development branch with some features not due for release, and another that had the same commits except for the new features, call it BRANCH_B).

The development work flow is as follows: start with BRANCH_B, create a commit branch CHANGE_C, make changes and commit, then checkout BRANCH_A, create a commit branch, then cherry-pick changes from CHANGE_C. BRANCH_A is tracking BRANCH_B in this way, with its additional feature files.

In my case, (for some reason during rebasing on co-worker changes from the remote that BRANCH_B tracks, the project file for BRANCH_B got corrupted.

In this case, the solution is to save a copy of the project file for BRANCH_A (which is good and compiles), then checkout BRANCH_B, and replace its project file with the copy.

Initially, it will not compile, until all references to the feature files (from BRANCH_A) are removed from Target's Build Phases > Compile Sources.

Works great.