# Xcode 4 build succeeds, command line build fails?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild

I have a project in Xcode 4 (the latest non-beta version) that builds fine when built in Xcode itself. Specifically, the Ld command correctly uses the derived data directory (where build products, including a dependent static library, are placed).

However, when I build the same project from the command line, the Ld command fails, as it is trying to use the /build folder within the project, which is not being populated.

I've tried adjusting every build setting I know about, both in the parent and the dependent project.

Any ideas on where to start debugging this? I can provide more info as needed.

**Edit 1:** Full Xcode build command:

```
xcodebuild -project AppName.xcodeproj -target AppName -configuration "Config Name"
```

Where `AppName` and `Config Name` are both the correct values for the build.

**Edit 2:** Link (Ld) commands.

When built in Xcode (this works):

```
Ld /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-apkmkuhwuccsbpblulxcsafyxkwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName normal i386
cd /Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-apkmkuhwuccsbpblulxcsafyxkwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName -F/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-apkmkuhwuccsbpblulxcsafyxkwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-apkmkuhwuccsbpblulxcsafyxkwa/Build/Intermediates/AppName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppName.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lxml2 -all_load -ObjC -licucore -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lMyClientLibrary -lxml2 -lsqlite3.0 -framework Security -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework MediaPlayer -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework AudioToolbox -lz.1.2.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-apkmkuhwuccsbpblulxcsafyxkwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName
```

When built from command line using build command above (this fails):

```
Ld "build/AppName.build/Prod Ad Hoc-iphoneos/AppName.build/Objects-normal/armv6/AppName" normal armv6
cd /Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk "-L/Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName/build/Prod Ad Hoc-iphoneos" -L/Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName "-F/Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName/build/Prod Ad Hoc-iphoneos" -filelist "/Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName/build/AppName.build/Prod Ad Hoc-iphoneos/AppName.build/Objects-normal/armv6/AppName.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -lxml2 -all_load -ObjC -licucore -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -lMyClientLibrary -lxml2 -lsqlite3.0 -framework Security -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework MediaPlayer -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework AudioToolbox -lz.1.2.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/james/Code/ClientName-Depot/NameOfProject/trunk/AppName/build/AppName.build/Prod Ad Hoc-iphoneos/AppName.build/Objects-normal/armv6/AppName"
```

Which returns:

```
ld: library not found for -lMyClientLibrary
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Start by giving your complete xcodebuild command

Comment: Done, as well as the linker commands.  Not sure if the "problem" is that one build uses the build directory while the other uses the derived data directory, or that the .a of the client library isn't being copied to the correct place.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this. Could be a bug, but you'd think it would have been found quickly.  Have you asked on Apple's Xcode-users list?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok, so nearly 6 (billable) hours later, I've gotten the build to work correctly in Xcode and on the command line (and on the build server, the whole point of this exercise).

Along the way I would fix one problem just to cause another - I would apparently fix the linker/Ld problem, only to cause problems in compilation ("SomeClass undeclared (first use in this function)" or "SomeHeader.h: No such file or directory" errors were common).

It was one of those times that I adjusted nearly every setting I could find, so it's hard to say what exactly what wrong and what exactly fixed it.

**Things I think *might* have helped are are as follows:**

- Converted build to use an Xcode workspace & scheme (instead of project & target)
- Rearranged workspace to have the App project and static library as siblings (not as parent/child)
- Changed Xcode and workspace settings to use build locations specified in targets
- Change Build Products Path for App and Library to use ../build (both project files are contained in sibling subfolders of a master directory, so having them build into the same folder solved the original linker/Ld command problem, I *think*)
- Edited the App scheme to explicitly build the Library target, and build it before the App target
- In the Build Phases for the App target, explicitly add the Library under "Link Binary With Libraries"
- Change the location type of the Library's .a file reference to "Relative to Build Products"
- Added a "Copy Headers" build phase to the Library project, added the appropriate headers to the Public section
- Changed the Public Headers Folder Path of the Library project to "/include"
- Changed the Installation Directory of the Library to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)`
- Changed the Library Search Paths and the User Header Search Paths of the App target to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` (recursive)
- Added a Clean command before the build on my Jenkins build server
- Added explicit SDK and Arch arguments to the build command
- Removed spaces from build configuration name

Final build command looks like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ClientName.xcworkspace -scheme AppName -configuration "ProdAdHoc" -sdk iphoneos -arch "armv6 armv7"
```

Some useful resources I used while debugging this issue:

- http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/
- https://devforums.apple.com/thread/91711?start=25&tstart=0

Anyway, I hope I've peppered enough keywords above that anybody who has any similar build issues in the future stumbles upon this and finds it useful.  I have no clue how a workflow I did many times in Xcode 3.x got so messed up when I moved to Xcode 4, here's hoping Apple is able to clean this up in future releases.

This was a heck of a learning experience for me, and going through all of this did seem to clear up issues with autocomplete I was having beforehand.  I will say things could have been much worse; I could still be developing for SharePoint.

Comment: For future reference, making sure the right schemes were shared, and switching the xcodebuild command line tool to use to use workspaces and schemes worked for me.

Comment: Thanks to the billable client as well.

Comment: Confirmed. Using `-scheme X` instead of `-project Y -target Z` worked for me. (I didn't have to create any new schemes.)

Comment: I'm using -scheme but i'm getting this error "Ld /Users/confiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CloudMessage-afevkkqtjcnmoddycvosdhbgoraa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LTDMessaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CloudMessage.build/Release-iphoneos/LTDMessaging.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LTD\ Messaging normal arm64" I've cleared drived data and have done everything you asked above but it didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

I ran in to the same issue yesterday and was able to work it out. In an effort to narrow down what worked for James, I'll point to what I had to do. I had to add a workspace and switch to running xcodebuild with workspace/scheme instead of project/target.

Using workspace/scheme forced xcodebuild to use the DerivedData folder instead of the build output folder under the main project. This allowed the linker to find the associated static library.

This blog post was hugely helpful:

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/05/04/automated-ad-hoc-builds-using-xcode-4/

Comment: This post pointed me in the right direction. You need at least one scheme and you must specify it on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I was experimenting with my files I add the @implementation to the .h file and left the .m file empty. I don't believe this is your error but if anyone else gets it maybe check that you haven't done this.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you didn't import the .m files in your header files! Changing .m to .h fixed this for me!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work for you but in my case, I had more than one `main.m` file. All I had to do was detach one of the `main.m` from the target and it worked. Make sure you don't have more than one `main.m` in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the log of the build, asking to see all messages, you should see a terse line that says "link ..." that has little in the way of details. However if you right click that line and select "expand all transcripts" you get a very detailed line telling you what command was issued from within XCode.

That should help you to debug the issue.

Dave

Comment: Took a look at that, edited my original post with the Ld command from both Xcode and command line builds. Command line still fails to link though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar exception encountered,
it turn out that i got some (null) reference in project.pbxproj
after I clean up those null reference in the project.pbxproj, the command line build was success just like the xcode previously does.
Take a look at [Xcode 4 project: utility to clean up pbxproj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064476/xcode4-project-)
utility-to-clean-up-pbxproj-file

for more reference

Answer (score 0):

All of a sudden I got the same problem after a Clean, at first I panicked wen I watched:

**`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`**

... but it turned to be really easy to fix, no command line needed!

I clicked on my project's root (the one on the top with the blueprint icon with an "A") in the Navigator, then clicked the PROJECT section (you can click on the TARGET section as well) and then clicked the button in the bottom-middle called "Validate Settings".

XCode itself validated the project files and told me that the problem was a duplicated target definition, and offered to fix it... and voilá, the problem its gone!

Good luck!

Comment: you know @RacZo answers like these can really use a screenshot

Comment: I think, the question is 'the build is failed when building the apps from command line' not from the XCode GUI app...

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by going to "Library search path", and make sure all entries are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had this issue when I was developing a `static library`. I had the `static library` target with all the production code, and a test target that pulled in the `MyStaticLib.a` file as a framework.

Tests ran just fine in Xcode, but not in the terminal using `xcodebuild`. The problem ended up being that the `static library` target was compiling for `Standard architectures`, while the test target wanted to compile for `Standard architectures (including 64-bit)`. Switching the test target to `Standard architectures` fixed everything.