# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (swiftyJSON)

Tags: xcode, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to compile an app i got from github and got these error.

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: Manifest.lock: No such file or directory error: 
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.`
```

podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'SwiftWeather' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'xcode7.1'
end

target 'SwiftWeatherTests' do
    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
end
```

so what I did is to remove the workspace file and run pod install again as suggested in [CocoaPods Errors on Project Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072396/cocoapods-errors-on-project-build)
but after that, I got a new error. *below*

```
Ld /Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftWeather.app/SwiftWeather normal x86_64
    cd /Users/alexisalvarez/Documents/iOS/finalproject/SwiftWeather-master-1
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Intermediates/SwiftWeather.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftWeather.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftWeather.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework SwiftyJSON -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Intermediates/SwiftWeather.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftWeather.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftWeather.swiftmodule -framework Pods_SwiftWeather -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Intermediates/SwiftWeather.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftWeather.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftWeather_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alexisalvarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftWeather-fgqbzqxcsjivdsgoyvlhlttkrwwj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftWeather.app/SwiftWeather
ld: framework not found SwiftyJSON
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm so confused. what's missing?

Comment: Are you using the workspace file to compile the project?

Comment: @skyline75489 i'm using the project file to compile the project . "SwiftWeather.xcodeproj"

Comment: You should use the workspace file. That's necessary when using CocoaPods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 iOS 7 CocoaPods Linker Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972280/xcode-5-ios-7-cocoapods-linker-error)

Comment: Voting to close. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972280/xcode-5-ios-7-cocoapods-linker-error.

Comment: @skyline75489 OHH I see. thanks!