# Deleted GoogleMaps cocoa pod and now get a linker error

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

I no longer need google maps in my project. I deleted all the places where it was imported (obviously) but now am stuck with this linker error:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMaps
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972280/xcode-5-ios-7-cocoapods-linker-error

Comment: Cocoa pods is up to date, and I've tried "pod update" of course... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `pod 'GoogleMaps'` from your pod file and then run `pod update` in terminal

Comment: I did all of that, forgot to say so in the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Had to remove Google Maps from "Other linker flags" in Build Settings.