# Xcode 4 build schemes screwed up every time I change branches in Git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode4, git-branch

In Xcode 4, when I'm working when an iOS project, the Scheme drop down menu in Xcode's toolbar normally displays a scheme for iPhone X.X Simulator, iPad X.X Simulator and iOS Device.

When changing branches after having done something that affects the *.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file, all my schemes disappear from the scheme drop down.  If I close the project and reopen it, they come back.  This is extremely annoying.

**Here's what I'm doing:**

- Create a new iOS related project
- Stage + Commit everything in the master branch
- Create & switch to a new branch
- Add a new class to your project and Save All (CMD+S+option) or just build the project to save everything.
- Commit that change
- Switch back to the master branch

At this point, my schemes are screwed and I have to close the project and reopen it to get them back.

**Here's what they look like at the beginning:**
[image]

**Here's what they look like after following the steps I listed:**
[image]

Does anyone know of a way around this or is this just a bug in Xcode?  I submitted a bug report to Apple about it months ago and have not received a response.  I've also received no response to a question about it in the developer forums.

**Update**: If you have a project with multiple targets, only the schemes for the selected target get screwed up after switching branches.

**Update**: Here's my .gitignore

```
# the build
build

# temp nibs and swap files
*~.nib
*.swp

# OS X folder attributes
.DS_Store

# user-specific XCode stuff
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
```

Comment: Same problem here, anything that changes the pbxproj will screw up the schemes.

Comment: @Pascal do those files NEED to be versioned? I'm not familiar with XCode, but I'd think it might not like the caching or something.

Comment: @melee Yes, the pbxproj file needs to be versioned.

Comment: Is there any line needed to be cleaned up in that files? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064476/xcode4-project-utility-to-clean-up-pbxproj-file) or any conversion taking place that you could prevent? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549578/git-and-pbxproj)?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Xcode. Have you filed a bug with Apple yet at http://bugreporter.apple.com?

Comment: @Joey yeah, months ago unfortunately.

Comment: This happens everytime. It's most certainly a bug. I just click in the build target version box (5.0, etc) and then out again and it resets itself.

Comment: @Dylan Works for me too, that's better than closing/opening the project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens every time for me. It's most certainly a bug. I just click in the build target version box (5.0, etc) and then out again and it resets itself. No need to open and close the project.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? This is happening to me in xcode 6.0.1 and I have no idea how to fix it without recreating all my schemes every time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding and committing the .xcodeproj file? [I had a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435071/managing-xcodeproj-file-with-git-how-to-manage-the-configuration-for-branches) about how to manage the configuration with branches. I think both of the answers may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I'm committing the .xcodeproj file.  The link you provided is broken.

Comment: Okay. It should be working now. Sorry I couldn't help. I hope it helps someone else.